# How to remove image of tree in beamer progressbar theme

Tags: beamer, formatting

When I run:

```
\documentclass[color=option]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\usepackage[english] {babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, graphicx}
\usepackage{bibunits, tikz}

\usetheme{Antibes}
\useoutertheme{progressbar}
\useinnertheme{progressbar}
\usecolortheme{progressbar}
\usefonttheme{progressbar}

\progressbaroptions{headline=sections, frametitle=normal}
```

gives following error:

```
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map} <./ima
ges/tree04.jpg>] (./Carro_and_Mira_real_v6.toc)
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.34 \end{frame}
```

Using

```
\progressbaroptions{headline=sections, title=normal}
```

executes, but the tree remains. The previous entry under this topic did not fix. I also deleted the image from the tree image from the file.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Where can we gat the outer theme `progressbar`; it's not included in the standard `beamer` themes.

Comment: From this site: http://recherche.noiraudes.net/en/LaTeX.php

Answer (score 3):

The definition of the `frametitle` template given in `beamerinnerthemeprogressbar.sty` is buggy (there's a `\fi` missing; I also changed a `centering` environment (another incorrection) for a `\centering` command). The following code contains a fix for the bug (there are also some blank spaces which might be intentional or not, so I didn't do any changes there):

```
\documentclass[color=option]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\usepackage[english] {babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, graphicx}
\usepackage{bibunits, tikz}

\usetheme{Antibes}
\useoutertheme{progressbar}
\useinnertheme{progressbar}
\usecolortheme{progressbar}
\usefonttheme{progressbar}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{myprogressbar theme}{
\edef\tempa{normal}
\ifx\progressbar@frametitle\tempa
  {\centering
  \textbf{\insertframetitle}
  \par}
\else
\edef\tempa{picture-subsection}
\ifx\progressbar@frametitle\tempa
\parbox[c]{0.13\textwidth}{\pgfuseimage{headlineimage}}
\parbox[c]{0.85\textwidth}{
  \usebeamercolor{frametitle}{\scriptsize \ifx\insertsection\@empty\ \else\insertsection\fi\ifx\insertsubsection\@empty\else\ \progressbar@separator\ \insertsubsection\fi}\\[-0.3cm]\rule{0.7\textwidth}{0.5pt}\par%\vskip-1cm\rule{0.7\textwidth}{0.5pt}\par
  \textbf{\vphantom{Hp}\insertframetitle}
}
\else
\edef\tempa{picture-section}
\ifx\progressbar@frametitle\tempa
\parbox[c]{0.13\textwidth}{\pgfuseimage{headlineimage}}
\parbox[c]{0.85\textwidth}{
  \usebeamercolor{frametitle}{\scriptsize \ifx\insertsection\@empty\ \else\insertsection\fi}\\[-0.3cm]\rule{0.7\textwidth}{0.5pt}\par%\vskip-1cm\rule{0.7\textwidth}{0.5pt}\par{}
  \textbf{\vphantom{Hp}\insertframetitle}
}
\else
\parbox[c]{0.13\textwidth}{\pgfuseimage{headlineimage}}
\parbox[c]{0.85\textwidth}{
%  %~ \usebeamercolor{frametitle}{\scriptsize \ifx\insertsection\@empty\ \else\insertsection\fi}\\[-0.3cm]\rule{0.7\textwidth}{0.5pt}\par%\vskip-1cm\rule{0.7\textwidth}{0.5pt}\par
  \usebeamercolor{frametitle}{\scriptsize\  }\\[-0.3cm]\rule{0.7\textwidth}{0.5pt}\par%\vskip-1cm\rule{0.7\textwidth}{0.5pt}\par
  \textbf{\vphantom{Hp}\insertframetitle}
}
\fi
\fi
\fi
}
\makeatother
\progressbaroptions{headline=sections, frametitle=normal}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please contact the package author and report the bug.